# Python 3.5.2 Windows x86-64 web-based, but installer not installing pip

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, pip

I am trying to install TensorFlow.  The installation instruction for Windows (https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows) have as first step to install Python 3.5.2.   And I'm doing the 'TensorFlow with CPU support only'.

Python was successfully installed in my computer as I can run it via the Start menu.

However, when I try to do the 2nd step of the installation instructions in order to install TensorFlow, this step says to:

```
  To install TensorFlow, start a terminal. Then issue the appropriate pip3 install command in that terminal. To install the CPU-only version of TensorFlow, enter the following command:

   C:\> pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow
```

But I'm getting an error when I perform the above statement, the error is

```
  'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, oprable program or batch file.
```

I looked at several postings in StackOverflow and tried the commands provided in one of the postings, but I would get the same type of error.

So, how is 'pip3' installed?  from what I read, it is supposed to be installed together with the installation, but obviously that did not happen.

How do I install it?  I need to install TensorFlow and it seems that it needs to be done via the pip3 installation tool.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: When you open the command line and enter "python", what happens?  It could be that you need to add Python to your PATH as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7

Answer (score 0):

Either set the system environment path variable to include the python 3.5.x path in it, or just cd into the correct python folder to run pip3 from there.

The folder in windows 10 should be something like this:

> C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Scripts

Open the terminal, cd to that path (change YOUR_USERNAME to the correct user) and then just run the following command:

```
pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow
```

and if you want the gpu version:

```
pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu
```

Pip3 is already installed when you install Python, so there is no need to do anything else.